# Calling Function with Range as Parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call a function with parameters as follows.

```
Private Sub Load_Data(File_Path As String)
    Dim data() As String
    'data = data_range_str(Range("rng_tbl_cell_ref_ttl_rows"), Range("rng_tbl_cell_ref_st_row"), Range("rng_CV_Col_No_A1"), Range("rng_cell_ref_sheet"))
    data = data_range_str(67, 6, 3, "Cell_Ref")
End Sub

Function data_range_str(row_count As Integer, offset_row As Integer, col As Integer, w_sheet_name As String) As String()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim data_range_string() As String
    ReDim data_range_string(row_count - 1) As String
    
    If row_count > 1 Then
        For i = 0 To row_count - 1
            data_range_string(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(w_sheet_name).Cells(offset_row + i, col)
        Next i
    ElseIf row_count = 1 Then
        data_range_string(0) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(w_sheet_name).Cells(offset_row, col)
    End If
    data_range_str = data_range_string
End Function
```

When I call the data_range_str function with excel range as commented in the codes, it shows [Error 1004:Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed]. But when I call the function with hardcoded parameters as in above code, it is OK.

Please help me to be able to call with variables.

Comment: So eg the range "rng_tbl_cell_ref_ttl_rows" is a single cell containing an integer? You could try harcoding all but one in turn to see if you can isolate the problem.

Comment: FYI in VBA `Integer` is a 16-bit integer. Use `Long` instead which uses the native 32-bit integers, and it won't overflow for values of 32767.

Comment: Also the `.Cells()` functions might return `Range()` objects, use `.Cells().Value` to make sure you return the value of a cell.

Comment: Could you explain in a few words what the function is supposed to do? Also, what does the sub do? You have the `File_Path` argument yet your function deals with `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0):

Not all details are given, so I had to guess a bit. This is my guess:

```
data = data_range_str(Range("rng_tbl_cell_ref_ttl_rows").Rows.Count, Range("rng_tbl_cell_ref_st_row").Row, Range("rng_CV_Col_No_A1").Column, Range("rng_cell_ref_sheet").Text)
```

It might be wrong, but I think you get the picture. A range is not a value, but an object with a lot of properties, such as row, column and a lot more.

Comment: Could be that OP has named ranges which contain a number or sheet name though.

Comment: Very much so. This is just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. When working with arrays defined from ranges, they need to be of `Variant` type, even though the contents are still of `String` type (or `Double`). Also the arrays need to be 1 based and have a rank of 2. These are just conventions that Microsoft has introduced. in their design of Excel/VBA

ALso no need to loop through the data, but rather just use the `.Resize()` function to reference multiple cells at once.

```
Private Sub Load_Data(File_Path As String)
    Dim data() As Variant, first as String
    data = DataRangeVals(67, 6, 3, "Cell_Ref")
    first = data(1,1)
End Sub

Public Function DataRangeVals(ByVal row_count as Long, byVal offset_row as Long, ByVal col as Long, ByVal w_sheet_name as String) as Variant()
    Dim data() as Variant
    If row_count>1 then
        data = Sheels(w_sheet_name).Cells(offset_row,col).Resize(row_count,1).Value
    ElseIf row_count=1 Then
       ReDim data(1 to 1, 1 to 1)
       data(1) = Sheels(w_sheet_name).Cells(offset_row,col).Value
    Else
       data = Array()  'Empty array
    End if
    DataRangeVals = data
End Function
```

There is a caveat in the *op* code, when it uses `.Cells()` as opposed to `.Offset()`, depending on the numbers passed to the function. With `offset_row=6` and `col=3` the corresponding cell address is

```
Cells(6,3) => "C6"
Offset(6,3) => "D7"
```

I just want to point out if the numbers are offsets from the first cell then you need to use the `.Offset()` function, or if the numbers are index values in the worksheets, then `.Cells()` is what is needed.

I want to offer a better alternative, that uses a source range, and the row count. So the referencing of the data is done outside the function where you have more control of how it is done.

```
Private Sub Load_Data(File_Path As String)
    Dim data() As Variant, first as String
    data = DataRangeVals(Worksheets("Cell_Ref").Cells(6,3), 67)
    first = data(1,1)
End Sub

Public Function DataRangeVals(ByVal r_src as Range, ByVal row_count as Long, Optional ByVal col_count As Long = 1) as Variant()
    Dim data() as Variant
    If row_count>1 Or col_count>1 then
        data = r_src.Resize(row_count,col_count).Value
    ElseIf row_count=1 And col_count=1 Then
       ReDim data(1 to 1, 1 to 1)
       data(1) = r_src.Value
    Else
       data = Array()  'Empty array
    End if
    DataRangeVals = data
End Function
```